# Dynamic key in psql row_to_json

Tags: json, psql

I have a query:

```
SELECT
row_to_json(( SELECT s FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        addr_id,
        target,
        status
) s
)) FROM shop;
```

which returns me such rows:

```
{"id": 1, "addr_id": 12, "target": null, "status": "ACTIVE"}
```

How can I rewrite my query, so value of row (addr_id) would be the key of my json:

```
{12: {"id": 1, "target": null, "status": "ACTIVE"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_build_object`.

```
SELECT
json_build_object(addr_id,
row_to_json(( SELECT s FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,         
        target,
        status
) s
))) FROM shop;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `json_build_object` instead of `row_to_json`. I think this makes the query more readable as well.

```
SELECT
  json_build_object(shop.addr_id, json_build_object(
    'id', shop.id,
    'target', shop.target,
    'status', shop.status
  ))
FROM shop;
```